# Getting data of more than 2 joined tables in Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Here are my tables.

```
╔════════════╤═╤══════════╤═╤═══════╗
║ Insurances │ │ Devices  │ │ Brands║
╠════════════╪═╪══════════╪═╪═══════╣
║ id         │ │ id       │ │ id    ║
╟────────────┼─┼──────────┼─┼───────╢
║ IMEI       │ │ type     │ │ name  ║
╟────────────┼─┼──────────┼─┼───────╢
║ device_id  │ │ name     │ │       ║
╟────────────┼─┼──────────┼─┼───────╢
║ user_id    │ │ brand_id │ │       ║
╚════════════╧═╧══════════╧═╧═══════╝
```

now I wanna show the results data in a table like

```
╔══════╤════════════╤═════════════╤══════════════╤═════════╗
║ IMEI │ brand_name │ device_name │ device_price │ user_id ║
╚══════╧════════════╧═════════════╧══════════════╧═════════╝
```

Imagine if it is AJAX and I have to join the tables before sending the data to the view. I have defined the relationships in models. but with the `with()` method I only can call 2 of em the same time and yet I dunno how to call them in the view.

Are there anyways to not use plain `DB::class` and just use eloquent?

Comment: Do you have relationships set up?

Comment: Okay. What would the problem be to parse the Device object with the insurance (I'd suspect a one-to-one relationship) and the brand (one-to-one again)? Obviously, you need to do the parsing in the controller or the model, not the view as you've mentioned.

Comment: @Andrius Could you be more clear?. You mean I get the Insurance then append the device and the brand to the end of it and send it to the view? If yes can you help me with the syntax? Have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this in your controller to get that result in your view.

```
$insurance = Insurance::with('device.brand')->find($id);

return json_encode([
  'imei' => $insurance->IMEI,
  'brand_name' => $insurance->device~>brand->name,
  'device_name' => $insurance->device->name,
  'device_price' => $insurance->device->price
  'user_id' => $insurance->user_id
```

]);

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you for teaching me that I can use it like that.

Comment: Only one modification, I have to use the chain still. for example Instead of `$insurance->brand->name` I should write `$insurance->device->brand->name` but still thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed so:

```
SELECT IMEI, B.name AS Brand_Name, D.name AS Device_Name, D.price, user_id
FROM Insurances I
INNER JOIN Devices D ON I.device_id = D.id
INNER JOIN Brands B on D.brand_id = B.id
```